# How can I disable animations for Vuetify v-expansion-panel component?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'd like to be able to disable the open/close animations for the v-expansion-panel component, i.e. the panel should instantly appear opened/closed when changes are made. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

It works on me.

```
<style lang="scss">
 .v-item-group.v-expansion-panels {
    &,
    & .v-expansion-panel,
    & .v-expansion-panel-header,
    & .v-expansion-panel-content {
      transition: none !important;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Is this a "cannot reproduce"? In that case please delete and wait for your commenting privilege. If this is supposed to be an answer according to [answer] you probably want to add some explanation to your code-only post.